# Flask-socketio AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'sid'

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I am getting this error: `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'sid'` when using socketio in flask. Here is the output:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/user/tennisprogram/application.py", line 34, in create_game_post
    join_room(str(gameid))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 865, in join_room
    sid = sid or flask.request.sid
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'sid'
```

Here is the code I'm using. If you need something other than the backend please let me know and I'd be happy to include it :).
Input:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, request, render_template, session, url_for
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room, close_room

app = Flask(__name__)
socket = SocketIO(app)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'secret-key'

games = [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

class Game:
    def __init__(self, player1, player2, id):
        self.id = id
        self.infodictionary = {"player1_name":player1, "player1_score":["0", "0", "0"], "player2_name":player2, "player2_score":["0", "0", "0"]}

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/create_game")
def create_game():
    return render_template("create_game.html")

@app.route("/create_game/post", methods=["POST"])
def create_game_post():
    if "host" in session:
        return "Already hosting a game" #Handle later
    for gameid, game in enumerate(games):
        if game == None:
            game = Game(request.form.get("player1"), request.form.get("player2"), gameid)
            games[gameid] = game
            session["host"] = gameid
            return redirect(url_for('game', id=game.id))
    return "No game slot available" #Handle later

@app.route("/game/<id>")
def game(id):
    join_room(str(id))
    if int(id) == session["host"]:
        return render_template("score.html", host=True, game=games[int(id)])
    else:
        return render_template("score.html", host=False, game=games[int(id)])

@socket.on("host-update")
def update(data):
    p1 = data["player1_score"]
    p2 = data["player2_score"]
    games[int(data["id"])].infodictionary["player1_score"] = p1
    games[int(data["id"])].infodictionary["player2_score"] = p2
    emit("update", {"player1_score":p1, "player2_score":p2}, room=data["id"])

#Handling join game
'''
@socket.on("joingame")
def join(data):
    r = data["room"]
    join_room(r)
'''

@app.route("/join_game")
def join_game():
    return render_template("join_game.html")
    #join_game.html will redirect user to join_game_post. The socket will activate in join_game.html

@app.route("/join_game/join", methods=["POST"])
def join_game_post():
    id = request.form.get("id")
    return redirect(url_for("game", id=id))

@app.route("/del")
def delete_host():
    games[int(session["host"])] = None
    del session["host"]
```

Comment: have you solved the problem? Do update an answer that worked for you if you can

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the answer here about [AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'sid'](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/445)

I believe that your error maybe caused by this line

```
*emit("update", {"player1_score":p1, "player2_score":p2}, room=data["id"])
```

Quoting the reason from the source above

> emit() function has a default of emitting to the sender of an originating event. This default only makes sense when you call the function from an event handler. You are calling it from a route, which does not have the Socket.IO context (in particular, request.sid).
>
> Do you know to which user(s) you want to emit an event from this
>   route? If you want to emit to all your connected clients, add
>   broadcast=True. If you know the sid of the user you want to address,
>   then add room=sid. You also need to specify the namespace, so add
>   namespace='/' or use the proper namespace name.

The error could also be as simple as, **user has been disconnected before being routed/redirected.**

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue an solved it by removing the call to join_room. So I think join_room can only be used in the context of @socket.on(...).